# How do I authenticate a user to access one page for a limited period of time in laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, token

I am working on an application that allows a social worker to conduct mental health assessments with their clients (usually children). This process normally happens face to face. A question is presented on a page, the social worker reads it to the client and the client indicates their answer (multiple choice from sad smiley to happy smiley), they click next and the next question is presented. I am trying to implement a feature to allow this process to happen remotely.

At the moment, only social workers have logins. The clients details are all in the db, so I would like to be able to email or sms a link with an authentication token that allows the client to have temporary access just to the questionaire page.

I am planning to use an API like pubnub or pusher to have the selected answers update on both the social workers view and the clients view as they change, so they can work through the questions together.

I am very new to Laravel and I am unsure how to go about creating a temporary session.

Looking at the documentation, there seems to be a number of ways to do authentication.

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use signed URLs in Laravel. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/urls#signed-urls

Signed URLs can be temporary, from the docs:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

return URL::temporarySignedRoute(
    'unsubscribe', now()->addMinutes(30), ['user' => 1]
);
```

later in your controller:

```php
if (! $request->hasValidSignature()) {
        abort(401);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that could be just what I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome. accept the answer if you think it's correct.

Comment: Yes, I know how SO works. I will absolutely accept the answer once I have tried it and had success. I won't accept it based on "thinking" it's correct.

Comment: This doesn't seem to provide the solution. Using a signed url still results in having to log in as a user, which I am trying to avoid

Comment: I don't think it is related to authentication. Signed url has only one job, makes sure that the URL is 1- from you, and 2- isn't manipulated. It has nothing to do with authentication. just generate a random number called `session_id` and generate a singed temporary URL for it. the only problem with this method is that the user may share the link with someone the ink isn't intended to.

Comment: I'm not so soncerned about the link being shared at the moment. My primary concern is providing access to the page. As I mentioned, I don't want clients to have to have a login. The social worker who is logged in should be able to invite them to the session with a link and the client should be able to view the page. I have tired adding auth exceptions for functions in the controller, but that doesn't work unless I except all the API routes used to fetch data from the db. I am starting to suspect there is no simple way around this

Comment: I think if you configure your routes correctly you can do this, the worker generates the invite link, this link should point to a  non-protected route , it should work

Comment: Yeah, my big problem is that the view also consumes a whole host of API to get organisation, and user data, client data, questionnaire data etc. So even when I exclude the function, I still hit the login page (I assume) because of api calls to protected routes. I have started looking into creating a gate to authenticate clients based on the client table, using their id and case number, and having the link that is sent, contain a login token... I'm not really sure how to go about that just yet. But it  would let me authenticate them and restrict their access just to the assessment page.

Comment: Yeah, those things are more complicated but  are more secure, flexible, and customizable. Rather than my simple solution, good luck implementing it!